# Anchor tag not working when we refresh the page or navigate to the page for the first time

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular12

We are currently using Angular Version 12 and implemented anchor tags in couple of our pages.

Following is how we configured our Routing Module:

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
initialNavigation: 'enabled',
scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy',
anchorScrolling: 'enabled'
})],
exports: [RouterModule]
})

So when we navigate to "localhost:4200/emp#grades" for the first time then the "#grades" is removed from the url and the page does not scroll to the anchor tag. Now if I manually go to the URL and add "#grades" and then press enter then it will scroll to the div which has id "grades". If I refresh the page again it stops working. So only manually adding the fragment in the url is working.

Can someone let me know what is causing this issue.